# Operator must take 'void'

Tags: c++, class, conversion-operator

Suppose I have two classes:

```
// A struct to hold a two-dimensional coordinate.
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

// A struct identical to Point, to demonstrate my problem
struct Location
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

I would like to implicitly convert a `Location` to a `Point`:

```
Point somePoint;
Location someLocation;

somePoint = someLocation;
```

So, I added this `operator` inside `Point`:

```
operator Point(Location &other)
{
    // ...
}
```

Upon which I compile with `g++ 4.9.2` on Debian, and receive this error:

```
error: 'Point::operator Point(Location &other)' must take 'void'
```

It sounds like the compiler wants the operator to accept no arguments, but that doesn't seem right -- unless I'm using the operator incorrectly. What is the real meaning behind this error?

Comment: You need either a `Point` constructor taking `Location`: `Point(const Location&)` (this would be a member of `Point` class); or a conversion operator from `Location` to `Point`: `operator Point() const;` (this would be a member of `Location` class). You are trying some weird mix of the two that makes no sense, and is not syntactically valid.

Comment: How would you use the operator if it took an argument? Are you thinking `foo.Point(foo)` is the right syntax?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's why the error seemed odd to me! I thought creating an operator in this way would let me assign one struct type to another -- Just a misunderstanding of documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[User-defined conversions operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) are defined as a **member function** for the type **from** which you want to convert to a different type. The signature is (inside `Location` class):

```
operator Point() const; // indeed takes void
// possibly operator const& Point() const;
```

Another possibility is to provide a [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) for `Point`:

```
Point(Location const& location);
```

Comment: I understand now. It looks like it would be simplest to implement the converting constructor; Thank you.

Comment: @Litty Maybe you could go a little further as to why aren't these identical-looking classes in any relationship? Shouldn't `Location` have-a `Point`? Shouldn't `Location` be-a `Point`?

Comment: Of course. I'm working with two libraries which use their own coordinate structs. I have my own functions that manipulate these coordinates; I'm making one struct the "primary" coordinate, and converting the other struct to and from this primary struct. The coordinate members are unfortunately named differently, I can't leverage templates here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overload the operator(). What you want to do is create a custom constructor that takes a point. The compiler with call this when you do the assignment or overload the assignment operator.

```
   Location( Point& p){
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
   }

   Location& operator= ( Point& p){
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            return *this;
   }
```

This will get this to compile

```
  Point somePoint;
  Location someLocation;

  somePoint = someLocation;
  Location loc = somePoint;
```

Comment: The `operator=` is not necessary ; implicit conversion will find the constructor